# Make Rails 5 API Read-Only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I want to make my Rails 5 API app to be read-only i.e. to accept only GET requests.

Currently I've used scaffold to build the necessary routes & controllers. As the use case requires only reading info, I want the app to accept only GET requests.

Another thing I want to know is how can update the data if the app is made read-only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to declare your app read-only and prevent yourself from writing code that writes to the database. The best you can do is only add GET routes and make sure that you do not write to the database in those actions.

You could use a tool like [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) to give yourself a GUI to change the data when you log in as an administrator. Or you could just access the data with `rails console`.

Comment: In that case, anyone can send a POST request & spam my database?

Comment: No, ActiveAdmin requires logging in to write to the database. Only you would know your user name and password.

Comment: If you do not define a POST in your routes file then if they send a POST they will get an error.

Comment: My Routes file:-
`Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
end`

Comment: Change `resources :users` to `resources :users,  only: [:index, :show] `